# Menu's drop-down angle (font awesome icon) is only displaying small rectangle with the unicode of f107

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, wp-nav-walker

This is a WordPress site using **Colorlib's Shapely Theme** and the **Shapely Companion plugin**.  (Note: This is a `bootstrap theme`, and uses `bootstrap-navwalker`.  I am also using a *child theme* to customise the site.)

The site can be found here:  [www.brightongate.com.au](http://www.brightongate.com.au/)

The font-awesome angle-down arrow used to display on the menu line, next to the Home page link.  At some point it stopped showing the arrow, and instead only shows a small rectangle box with the unicode inside: `f107`.  (Note:  I haven't done any changes myself to this site for a long time - outside of updating plugins, etc.)

Here is the relevant code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul id="menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1033" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-642 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-1033 dropdown active">
            <a title="Home" href="http://www.brightongate.com.au/">Home </a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
            <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1233" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-642 current_page_item menu-item-1233 active">
                    <a title="[ Welcome to Brighton Gate - home page ]" href="http://www.brightongate.com.au/">[ Welcome to Brighton Gate – home page ]</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1021" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1021">
            <a title="Log In" href="http://www.brightongate.com.au/login/">Log In</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Using inspect on the home menu item, you can see that the `span` surrounding the font-awesome code is grayed out, making it look like it isn't being executed:

```
<span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

According to others (posted online) that have similar issues (with font-awesome icons not displaying drop-down icon), it appears that the *problem might either be* that the **font family isn’t correct** (ie: Font Awesome 5 Free) or that the **incorrect all.min.css file** has been uploaded.

I have tried to verify both of these possible issues as follows:

Still looking with inspect, clicking on the line of `i class` code, I can see that the class `fa` is defined using the correct `font-weight` & `font-family`:

```
.fa, .fas {
  font-weight: 900;
}
.fa, .far, .fas {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```

Looking at the Shapely `function.php` file, you can see that it includes the font-awesome css file:

```
    // Add Font Awesome stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
```

And also from View Source I can see the font-awesome css is indeed brought in (showing a version of 5.9.5)

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css'  href='http://www.brightongate.com.au/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/css/fontawesome/all.min.css?ver=5.9.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Can someone see any other issues why the `span` code surrounding the font-awesome drop-down icon isn't being executed?

Or is there a way to verify that I have the correct version of the `all.min.css` file being used?

Thanks for any help on this matter.
Sunny Oz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue often occurs when the theme or other files are outdated,

You can solve this problem with a [Wordpress plugin by Font Awesome](https://wordpress.org/plugins/font-awesome),

It is free and it definitely solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much @Zaid Munshi .  That did the trick!  I was thinking that bringing in another version of font-awesome css would cause problems with this Theme, but it all seems to be working perfectly.  I appreciated your quick response!